# C# Web Service not picking up custom class with IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis

Currently using Visual Studio 2015 to build a web service application using .NET 4.0.

My interface class has 1 method that I want exposed on the service:

```
public interface IEvaluateGroupService{

    [OperationContract]
    EvaluateGroupResponse EvalGroup(EvaluateGroupRequest _request)

}
```

EvaluateGroupResponse and EvaluatGroupRequest are custom classes used by the web service.

My issue is that when I build the service and deploy it to IIS, it recognizes the existence of the Request/Response classes when I reference it, but it's missing the fields in the classes.

I.e. if I reference my webservice in C#:

```
EvaluateGroupService.EvaluateGroupRequest _request = new EvaluateGroupService.EvaluateGroupRequest();
```

This doesn't throw an error. I can't however access any of the fields in my class. Additionally, I defined my request class's constructor to take 1 argument. If I try to call that constructor, I get an error stating that my request doesn't have a constructor that takes 1 argument.

Below are my Request/Response classes:

Request:

```
namespace EvaluateGroupService
{
[DataContract]
public class EvaluateGroupRequest
{
    private int accountKey;
    private DateTime? startDate = null;
    private DateTime? endDate = null;


    public EvaluateGroupRequest(int initAcctKey)
    {
        AccountKey = initAcctKey;

    }
    public DateTime? EndDate
    {
        get
        {
            return endDate;
        }

        set
        {
            endDate = value;
        }
    }
    public DateTime? StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            return startDate;
        }

        set
        {
            startDate = value;
        }
    }
    public int AccountKey
    {
        get
        {
            return accountKey;
        }

        set
        {
            accountKey = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Response:

```
namespace EvaluateGroupService
{
[DataContract]
public class EvaluateGroupResponse

{
    private bool success;
    public bool Success
    {
        get
        {
            return success;
        }

        set
        {
            success = value;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Only for test purpose, can you add an empty contructor to EvaluateGroupRequest class? (i think that is necessary for serialization/deserialization of the message)

Comment: You need to decorate the fields in your requests/responses with the `[DataMember]` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing DataMember attribute.....

```
 [DataMember]
 public DateTime? EndDate
    {
        get
        {
            return endDate;
        }

        set
        {
            endDate = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to include a custom constructor as opposed to the default one? I wasn't able to find a way.

Comment: I do not think so it is possible in DataContract class. But why do you need custom constructor?? you can always have Data Member

Comment: Like in your example, AccountKey can be Data member too

Comment: I want to enforce the account key and start date as mandatory fields to create a request.

Comment: I think there is way to tell member is mandatory using attribute

Comment: There you go.   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d9e45449-cc50-42e2-b955-75ab86f01d4f/isrequired-attribute-on-datamember?forum=wcf

Answer (score 0):

You need to decorate the fields in your requests/responses with the `[DataMember]` attribute.

You used to have to add the `DataContract` attribute to the class, but that is now added by default. However, WCF doesn't assume the fields are accessible.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```